# Python module to get geo coordinates for a city using a local data source?

Tags: python, geocoding

Is there a Python module that gives reasonable latitude/longitude coordinates for an address consisting of a (city, state) combination, using a database that's stored on a system locally (rather than relying on calls to some third-party API)? Coordinates that are reasonably close to the city center would be fine.

Answer (score 1):

You need a database. There are some out there that you could potentially use, such as [the one at maxmind.](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/geolite/)  If you have a match on city name or postal code then you will have the lat/long for the city.

Fields in the maxmind database include:
`locId,country,region,city,postalCode,latitude,longitude,metroCode,areaCode`

Comment: AFAIK Maxmind db gives you country/city by IP. OP asks for "latitude/longitude coordinates for an address consisting of a (city, state) combination"

Comment: @warvariuc, so I had it backwards, I will re-do my answer. The database has city names and lat / longs, so it will work either direction.